# Generating all numbers between 000 and 999 without repetition and in random order

Tags: php

I need to generate all numbers between 000 and 999 without repetition and in order. Currently i am using the code

```
    for($count = 0; $count <= 999; $count++)
    {
            echo str_pad($count, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "<br />\r\n";
    }
```

But it is producing the numbers in sequence. So can someone provide me the code for generating them in non-sequential order and without repetition

Comment: "So can someone provide me the code " - that's not how SO works...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a shuffle function to do that.
First, create an array with values {0,1,2,3,...,999}
Then, use a shuffle function to shuffle the order of element in the array.
Read the example code in this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: can you suggest me how to create an array of numbers between 000 and 999. Actually i am not good enough at programming

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php should help you to make that array. You may find this sort of thing simpler to learn in a language like python, but that's just my own opinion.

Comment: @SahilAgarwal copy the example code in the page. Then replace `$numbers = range(1, 20);` with `$numbers = range(0, 999);`